# Bike commuting on the Captial Crescent Trail in Washington DC

Tags: commuter, bikeroutes

I am moving to the Washington DC area and will be working in Bethesda at the NIH. It looks like living in/near Georgetown and commuting out on the [Capital Crescent Trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_Crescent_Trail) could be really nice. I was curious what the path conditions are like (e.g., potholes, speed bumps, road crossings, and bike/jogger/car traffic). I would also be interested in other areas that would provide a nice sub 10 mile bike commute to Bethesda.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question as is due to the ability for the information to quickly change as far as trail conditions, and the audience being more mechanically oriented.  However, I would take it to a social media group that commutes in the area.  It might be a tricky one but it is easy to find wide area ones and then narrow it down from there.  I found one for my region that was very helpful in getting local touring info.

Comment: @BPugh as the "trail" is paved I don't think the condition will change that quickly and the number of road crossings and traffic during commuting times is probably pretty static. As for the audience, I thought it might be covered under "people who commute on bicycles" and I checked in chat. That said, if you think it is off topic, close away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commuted often on this trail for awhile and loved it.

Most of the trail is free of vehicle traffic and has bridges going over roads. It's a heavily shaded trail that can provide a nice respite from the sun during the hot summer. Potholes are minimal, though minor cracks from tree roots are not uncommon. Also, there can be quite a bit of debris on the trail after a good wind storm.

Not too far out of the city the path has a wooden ramp, in good condition, that last about 50 yards.

During the commuting hours, foot traffic exists, but I remember going at a pretty good rate with no issues.

There are a couple poorly lit tunnels, so you will want a bike light.